# unit testing angular factory with $http

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I triple checked everything and still there seems to be an error

service :

```
angular.module('app.services')
        .factory('eventService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
                return {
                    get: function() {
                        var deffered = $q.defer();

                            $http.get('x')
                            .success(function(data) {
                                deffered.resolve(data);
                            })
                            .error(function(){
                                deffered.reject("could not access events");
                            });

                            return deffered.promise;
                    }
                };
            }])
```

Unit test:

```
describe('when fetching events by service', function() {
    var service;
    var $httpBackend;
    var appConfig;
    beforeEach(function() {
        module("ngMockE2E");
        module("app.services");
        inject(function(eventService, _$httpBackend_) {
            service = eventService;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        });
    });
     it('should get items', function(){
           $httpBackend.expectGET('x').respond([{ name : 1}]);
           var promise = service.get();
           promise.then(function(data){
              console.log(data); 
           });

           $httpBackend.flush();
       });
});
```

I am getting the following error on the .flush()

```
Error: No pending request to flush !                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            at /test/lib/angular-mocks.js:1148                                                                                                                                                                                 
            at /test/unit/services/EventServiceSpec.js:26
```

Also how do I ensure that the $httpBackend set up is being used by eventService. That is eventService is generated with the dependency of $httpBackend and not $http ? Which I think I might be the reason for the error.

Comment: did you got it to working?

Answer (score 0):

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('x').respond([{ name : 1}]); // when you receive a request expectation, respond X
$httpBackend.expectGET('x').respond([{ name : 1}]); // add a request expectation and respond X
$httpBackend.expectGET('x'); // add a request expectation
```

so you are just setting up the behaviour when you make a request instead of actually adding that request expectation.

You need to use:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('x').respond([{ name : 1}]);
```

or

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('x').respond([{ name : 1}]);
$httpBackend.expectGET('x');
```

Comment: Hey @Diego thanks for the answer. I understand the difference between the .expectGET and whenGET now . However I am still getting the same error and I assume it coz I THINK I haven't set up/ injected the service correctly as I am still getting the same error after the change you suggested.